# how to get a specific row values from database using servlet?(without using any sql conditions.)

Tags: sql, database

I want to display a table from a database. However I only want to display 5 rows (from 6th to 10th) only given the name of the table.

It is a dynamic process, so the query doesn't depend on the table values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you will use the "select * from tbname limit 5".

On a second thought doing this will give you the first 5 value based on your search criteria, if this is what you want. So you still need to be clear about your search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no such thing as "first" in a table. You need to impose your idea of firstness using the " ORDER BY " clause.

In your case I would select whatever you want from the table order by whatever you think "first" means and simply loop past the first five rows.

`SELECT NAME, AGE, SCORE FROM GAMERESULT ORDER BY SCORE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command limit for example you can say:

```
select * from table a limit 5,10
```

Comment: i am using this query---> "SELECT SKIP 5 FIRST 5 * FROM table1"; but it displays ERROR in disp java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SKIP 5 FIRST 5 *'.

Answer (score 0):

```
select from table name limit n
```

Where `n` is the number of rows you want to fetch.

I think this will work.

Comment: i am using this query---> "SELECT SKIP 5 FIRST 5 * FROM table1"; but it displays ERROR in disp java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SKIP 5 FIRST 5 *'.

Answer (score 0):

@mariana soffer is correct but it fetches from row no 6 to 15 also it can be used only with some database like mysql 
for other databases see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Result_limits

Comment: i am using this query---> "SELECT SKIP 5 FIRST 5 * FROM table1"; but it displays ERROR in disp java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SKIP 5 FIRST 5 *'.